# Converting txt data into excel using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

How to convert this data?

[image]

into like this:

[image]

To be clear would like to convert text file into Excel using pandas, also
to be able to do something with data, like sorting e.t.c the data before saving it.

My attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('kat2002_01-12.8', sep='\t')
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index=False)
```

but it didn't work:

[image]

Comment: You are discouraging people from helping you by providing a very poorly written question without minimal reproducible example. Please, give it a read, edit your question about and nice people of SO will surely help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is the first file a TSV format? Why don't you just import it in Excel with Tab as delimiter?

Comment: It seems that not all columns are tsv format

Comment: There are a lot  of files that I need to convert, using excel with Tab as delimiter takes too much time for me

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

with open("your_text_file.txt","r") as f:
  first_line = f.readline()
  # This would create columns as per your text file
  df = pd.DataFrame(columns = firstline.split("\t")) # assuming your entire data is tab seperated
  counter = 0
  for line in f.readlines(): # iterating over remaining data
    df.loc[counter] = line.split("\t")
    counter+= 1
  df.to_excel("your output.xlsx")
```

Comment: thank you for your help @Surya Tej but the same result

Comment: I believe there is no constant spacing in your input file.. I would say split based on empty spaces, remove unwanted spaces and then add to pandas dataframe